# Performance difference between AE and Blender compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, performance

[image]

I tested the curve effects in Blender and AE using a 5k x 3k image.

Like this, Blender has a slightly slower performance.

I'm curious about the principle of the program that causes the difference in performance between Blender and AE.

Comment: Blender is an open source softwares developed mostly by volunteers, After effects is backed by the resources of a multi million dollar company.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software comparison

Comment: I'm sorry that my question has the nuanced comparison.
 But I wanted to know how Blender processes images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same result I can see in other software, for example Natron. The difference between blender and other software is:

- Blender compose images in maximum settings in full resolution in one
  pass.  Even if image scaled in 10%, blender compose 100% resolution version and scale it down.
- AE and Natron makes first pass in low resolution and low
  quality settings, and after you stop moving a mouse, starts to compose
  image in maximum (or screen resolution) settings